# Как называется параметр в реестре "Уровни" звука записывающих устройств

Tags: windows, аудио, bat, реестр

Как называется параметр в реестре "Уровни" звука записывающих устройств

Пока нашел только это HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\capture

P.S. и есть ли возможность менять этот уровень с помощью BATника.

Answer (score 0):

Уровень звука, предположительно, хранится не в реестре, а в двоичных файлах в каталоге **%WINDIR%\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData**. Структура файлов неизвестна и может различаться в разных версиях ОС.

Легкого способа изменить его через bat-файл нет. Можно сделать это через Powershell вызовом COM-интерфейса *IAudioEndpointVolume*:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
[Guid("5CDF2C82-841E-4546-9722-0CF74078229A"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
interface IAudioEndpointVolume
{
    // f(), g(), ... are unused COM method slots. Define these if you care
    int f(); int g(); int h(); int i();
    int SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(float fLevel, System.Guid pguidEventContext);
    int j();
    int GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(out float pfLevel);
    int k(); int l(); int m(); int n();
    int SetMute([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bMute, System.Guid pguidEventContext);
    int GetMute(out bool pbMute);
}
[Guid("D666063F-1587-4E43-81F1-B948E807363F"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
interface IMMDevice
{
    int Activate(ref System.Guid id, int clsCtx, int activationParams, out IAudioEndpointVolume aev);
}
[Guid("A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
interface IMMDeviceEnumerator
{
    int f(); // Unused
    int GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(int dataFlow, int role, out IMMDevice endpoint);
    int  GetDevice(string pwstrId, out IMMDevice endpoint);
}
[ComImport, Guid("BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E")] class MMDeviceEnumeratorComObject { }
public class Audio
{
    static IAudioEndpointVolume Vol()
    {

        IMMDeviceEnumerator enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumeratorComObject() as IMMDeviceEnumerator;
        IMMDevice dev = null;
        Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(1, /*eMultimedia*/ 1, out dev));
        if(dev==null)System.Console.WriteLine("dev = null");
        IAudioEndpointVolume epv = null;
        System.Guid epvid = typeof(IAudioEndpointVolume).GUID;
        Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(dev.Activate(ref epvid, /*CLSCTX_ALL*/ 23, 0, out epv));
        return epv;
    }
    public static float Volume
    {
        get { float v = -1; Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Vol().GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(out v)); return v; }
        set { Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Vol().SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(value, System.Guid.Empty)); }
    }
    public static bool Mute
    {
        get { bool mute; Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Vol().GetMute(out mute)); return mute; }
        set { Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Vol().SetMute(value, System.Guid.Empty)); }
    }
}
'@


[audio]::Volume  = 0.7 # Уровень звука в диапазоне от 0.0 до 1.0
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31751275/8674428)

Если нужно управлять конкретным устройством, заменить `enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint...` на `enumerator.GetDevice("(Endpoint ID)", out dev)`, где *(Endpoint ID)* - идентификатор устройства вида "{0.0.1.00000000}.{Guid}"